# String Switch Statement Not Working

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

This program's purpose is to translate Morse code into English. I've divided the program's execution logic into three cases: the translation of one Morse code character, two characters and three+ characters. This program tries to translate characters that fall under case three. If you can help, and decide to test the program, please input at least four morse code characters (between a and d)! Otherwise, expect some outofbounds exceptions!

---

What's wrong with the switch I used? I've read that, up until a few years ago, Java did not support switch statements that used Strings. Java now supports String switch statements and, if I'm not mistaken, my syntax agrees with the not-very-complex conventions of these statements. To determine whether the compiler first recognizes the switch's subject (i.e. `switch (aReferenceThatPointsToaString)`, I printed the reference in the line preceding the switch. No problem there. I also looked at whether cases could be executed if the switch's subject were explicitly stated. Instead of saying `switch (array3[i])`, I wrote in `switch ("._")` This test did result in a working switch, leaving me with the impression that `switch(array3[i])` isn't quite the same as `switch(aStringexpression)`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MorseToEnglish1 {

public static void main (String[]args){
    System.out.println("enter morse here");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String container = input.nextLine();

    char [] array = container.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == ' ')
        count++ ;
    }

    // count counts the number of times a space appears

    System.out.println(count);
    int [] array2 = new int [count];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == ' '){
            array2[counter] = i;
            counter ++ ;
        }
    }

    // array2 assigns the indexes of spaces to its members

    System.out.println(counter);

    String [] array3 = new String [array2.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < array3.length ; i ++)
        array3[i] = container.substring(array2[i], array2[i+1]);
        // array3 creates substrings based on these spaces
    System.out.print (array3[1]);
    System.out.print(array3[0]);

    // tests above

    for (int i = 0; i < array3.length; i ++){
        switch (array3[i]){
        case ("._"):
            { System.out.println("a");
            break; }
        case "_...":
            { System.out.println("b");
            break; }
        case "_._.":
            { System.out.println("c");
            break;}
        case "_..":
            { System.out.println("d ");
            break;}
        }   

    }   

    input.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Unless you are using Java 8, you cannot switch on Strings in Java

Comment: @Eenvincible:  You mean Java 7.

Comment: So be specific.  *Where* are you seeing an issue?  When I run this code I get an error well before the `switch`.  Do you have a specific way you're entering in your data?

Comment: I totally agree with @Makoto. can you explain your logic first? It seems you over complicate everything

Comment: I have to admit I must overcome an overwhelming urge to automatically downvote any post with a title "_[some language feature] does not work_".  I have to remind myself that I did indeed file a bogus compiler-bug report against IBM's PL/1 compiler back in the day (but I did find 3 real bugs in the compiler).

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Also, switch statements do not use curly braces to enclose each case. The entire switch block must be enclosed and that is it. See [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: One thing that would help you is a `default:` case that prints any input that is not matched by another case. Then you'd quickly see any unexpected processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your `switch` statement, there is a lot wrong with the rest of the program...

The problem is, your custom "split" process is leaving spaces within the text, so, if were to enter `._ _... _._. _..`, the array would be split into...

```
" _...", " _._."
```

Which is wrong on two accounts, one, it's missing stuff I entered and two, it's leaving the leading space character in the `String`, so when you try and compare the `String`s in the `switch` statement, you are actually trying to do something like...

```
"_...".equals(" _...")
```

Which will fail...

To start with, this "manual" splitting code...

```
char[] array = container.toCharArray();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == ' ') {
        count++;
    }
}

// count counts the number of times a space appears
System.out.println(count);
int[] array2 = new int[count];
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == ' ') {
        array2[counter] = i;
        counter++;
    }
}

// array2 assigns the indexes of spaces to its members
System.out.println(counter);

String[] array3 = new String[array2.length - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
    array3[i] = container.substring(array2[i], array2[i + 1]);
}
// array3 creates substrings based on these spaces
System.out.println(array3[1]);
System.out.println(array3[0]);
```

Should be replaced with...

```
String[] array3 = container.split(" ");
```

As I, frankly, have no idea what it's trying to achieve and it breaks if there is less than 4 "codes" on the input `String` and doesn't correctly parse the input anyway (throwing away values)

Answer (score 1):

Your splitting code is leaving leading space characters which cause them to not correctly match. You should instead be using a version of [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) in order to produce your array3. This will create the correct substrings with a lot less work.

Edit:
Your splitting code also appears to leave off the first and last morse codes which is why you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions when you input less than 4.

Answer (score -4):

From looking at the code you've got too many `}` curly braces. You only need one of those at the end of the switch statement.

```
case ("._"):
        {System.out.println("a");
        break;
    case "_...":
        {System.out.println("b");
        break;
    case "_._.":
        {System.out.println("c");
        break;
    case "_..":
        {System.out.println("d ");
        break;
        }
```

It should work. My assumption is of course that your problem is that your code doesn't compile. Which I'm pretty sure that the code you posted won't do.

Comment: Yet you leave all the opening curly braces?